# Who is the author of this contradictory poem starting "The night was dark and stormy"?

Tags: poetry, identification-request

Does anyone know the name of or the author of the poem below? My grandfather used to say it all of the time and I would like to read it at his funeral. It's very silly and goes something like this:

> The night was dark and stormy,
>   The sun was shining bright,
>   The victims lips were tightly sealed,
>   She screamed with all her might,
>   Oh kill me friend but spare my life,
>   The villain shot her dead,
>   A gay young girl skipped down the aisle,
>   Grey hairs on her bald head,
>   She recognized the dying girl,
>   "Oh who is this?", cried she,
>   The headless corpse raised up its head and said, "It's only me."

Comment: This other question about a similar self-contradictory poem might be of interest to you as well: [What is the origin of this contradictory poem?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2193/58)

Comment: I googled most of the phrases, and none of them turned up any matches.

Comment: This thread on [Mudcat.org](https://mudcat.org/thread.cfm?threadid=5936) is clearly talking about a related work or works, though mostly being described as songs rather than poems, so you may have success generally searching for 'lyrics' instead of 'poem'. One particular version seems promising 'And recognizing the dying man, she quickly yelled, "Who is he?"
The dead man raised his corpseless head and cried, "By the great Gods, 'tis Lizzy!"'

Comment: Welcome to the site, Lindsay.  I believe your question is a duplicate --this is a variant on the [same poem](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2193/what-is-the-origin-of-this-contradictory-poem) mentioned by Mithrandir, and Spagirl.  It has no one single author --it emerged from the folk tradition over the course of generations, and has hundreds of variations.